# How do I solve indentation errors in Python?

Tags: python, indentation

When I run the below code, I get indentation errors in many lines, such as line 6 and lines where I put `exit(0)`:

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold, How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man learn to type a number!")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")


def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move a bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you and slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:   
            print "The bear has moved from the door and you can go now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:    
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea waht that means."


def cthulhu_room():
    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
    print " He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if  "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead("Well that was tasty!")
    else:
        cthulhu_room()


def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

def start():
    print "You are in dark room."
    print "There is a door on your right and left."
    print "Which one do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starved.")


start()
```

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces? If you are using spaces, do you have consistent numbers of spaces (e.g. 2 vs 4)?

Comment: What is your python version ? Try using print();

Comment: @AnthonyGranger: 99% sure it's Python 2.

Comment: @vaultah never underestimate this last 1% !

Comment: If it was Python 3, there would also be errors on the lines with parentheses-less `print`s.

Comment: I have downloaded this version python-2.7.11rc1 and yes, I am mixing tabs with spaces....so I guess that's a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a problem. Convert all tabs to spaces. The standard indentation is four spaces per level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't mix tabs and spaces.
2. Use tools which will replace tabs with spaces (such as PyCharm).

By the way, you can use PyCharm to repair your broken indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing tabs and spaces.

To fix your file on Linux :

```
tr \\t '    ' < file_in.py > file_out.py
```

And on Windows (7+) :

```
powershell -Command "(gc file_in.py) -replace '\t', '    ' | Out-File file_out.py"
```